# Dsymutil warning "no debug symbols in executable"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, dsymutil

I am working on eliminating warnings for an iOS program in Xcode by fixing the problems causing the warnings as much as possible.  Thankfully, I have been mostly successful at this, but I have two warnings which refuse to go away:  I get a report of a "Dsymutil warning", which the relevant log says is reported when it tries to generate a .dSYM file.  The two warnings are:

> warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch armv7)
>
> warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch arm64)

I can make these warnings vanish by cleaning and cleaning the build folder.  However, they'll simply show up again when I compile again.

Relevant statistics:

Phones tested:  iPhone 5s, iPhone SE

OS:  iOS 10.3.2

Development environment:  Xcode 8.3.2

Build Active Architecture Only:  No

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting these warnings, and are they anything to worry about?  I'm not really finding anything particularly relevant via Google or in Apple's documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Clarification after the post:  That's "clean" and "clean build folder" and run, at which point the warnings vanish.  The warnings reappear when I run the program a second time.

Answer (score 1):

In your target Build Settings, try to 
turn on DWARF with dSYM, debugging symbols, and deployment
postprocessing.
Hope this will help...